# Unsigned and Signed in same expression: What rules apply?

Tags: c, integer, bit-shift, integer-promotion

I'm confused by the issue stated in the title. I've been told that in expressions involving both types of variables, signed are converted to/interpreted as unsigned. However, as the following code snippet shows, that isn't always the case.

Code:

```
unsigned int x = 1;
int y = -20;
printf("Right shift = %x, %d\n", y>>x, y>>x);
printf("If = %x, %d\n", y < x, y < x);
```

Result:

```
Right shift = fffffff6, -10                                        
If = 0, 0
```

The if statement returns the expected 0, -20 being cast to a very large unsigned integer, but the shift expression returns -10, making it evident that arithmetic and not logical shift has taken place. The x has been interpreted as signed rather than the y being interpreted as unsigned.

Could anyone clear this up for me?

Comment: and where is the `if` statement?

Comment: Modified code for clarity.

Comment: That's not an `if` statement, that's a print statement: just saying.

Comment: *"I've been told that in expressions involving both types of variables, signed are converted to/interpreted as unsigned"* is untrue. In an expression that has `unsigned short` and `short`, both are promoted to signed `int`s if representable.

Comment: `%x` tells `printf()` to ASSUME the corresponding argument is of type `unsigned`, and `%d` tells `printf()` to ASSUME the corresponding argument is of type `int`.   The behaviour is undefined if the assumption is invalid.   Since `y >> x` has type `int`, the usage of `%x` gives undefined behaviour.   It may happen to give a result that makes sense to you, but is not required to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this expression

```
y>>x
```

(the C Standard, 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 3 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.

That means that as `y` has the type `int` and `x` has the type `unsigned int` neither conversion (promotion) occurs. And

> 3. ...The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.

So the result of the expression has the type `int` - the type of the operand `y`. As `y` has a negative value then

> 5. ...IfE1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is 
>      implementation-deﬁned

As for this expression

```
y < x
```

then there is used the usual arithmetic conversions. The boths operands have the same rank so the operand `y` of the type `int` is converted to the type `unsigned int` and its binary representation as an object of the type `unsigned int` is greater than the binary representation of the operand `x`.

From the C Standard *6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
>   the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with unsigned integer type.

Comment: Thanks! To clarify: In shift operations each side is treated independently? Separate question: which operations act like the shift (sides treated independently) and which act like the if (both sides treated as one unit)? What is &, ^, +, -, /, *, etc?

Comment: @EdwardGaremo Yes, the integer promotions are performed separately for each operands. As for other operators then then im most cases the usual arithmetic conversions are performed.

Comment: Most or all? Is shift the only odd one out or is there another operator which works like it?

Comment: @EdwardGaremo the shift is special because the right hand side just needs to have range 0 ... width - 1. Actually it would not need to be promoted at all...

Comment: @EdwardGaremo It is the only operator where the integer promotions are performed on each operand.

Comment: Operators with multiple object operands (i.e., excluding `_Generic`, which takes a list of types) that do not convert operands to a common type are array subscripting (`a[i]`), function calls (arguments are separate), member accesses (`Structure.Member`, `StructurePointer->Member`), shifts, the conditional operator (`a ? b : c` does not convert `a`, and the result is a common type derived from `b` and `c`, but only one is evaluated), and the comma operator.